# Search array of array of strings with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nspredicate

I have a NSSearchController that searches an array of arrays. An example of this master array is

```
[["key1',"value1"],["key2","value2"]]
```

My search function is as follows:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    for (key, val) in zip(self.keys, self.values) {
        pairs.append([key,val])
    }

    filteredKeys.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    filteredValues.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let searcher = (self.pairs as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    println(searcher)

    for matched in searcher {
        var appendedKey = matched[0] as! String
        var appendedValue = matched[1] as! String
        filteredKeys.append(appendedKey)
        filteredValues.append(appendedValue)
    }

    pairs.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The problem is with my NSPredicate string, as I am searching an array of arrays, the SELF CONTAINS requires an exact string match to be in the array instead of it just containing it. I really want the subarrays of the master array to contain the string being searched.

I tried "name CONTAINS[c] %@" and "SELF BEGINSWITH[c] %@" Both fail. Does anyone know what predicate string to use to search an array of arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ANY SELF`.

```
let pairs = [["key1","value1"],["key2","value2"]]
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", "lue2")
let searcher = (pairs as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
println(searcher) // Prints the second element
```

From the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) for `ANY`:

> Specifies any of the elements in the following expression.